# Selection and Drag with TComboBox

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm using FireMonkey in Delphi 11.3 Alexandria.

I have a `TComboBox` on my main form. I'd like to allow the user to select an item from the list, and then drag that item to another control on the form (a `TStringGrid`).  Seems like I can either code to select an item, or code to drag the item, but not both.

Can someone point me to an example of what events to code for (and how) to do both?  Just setting the `DragMode` of the `TComboBox` to `dmAutomatic` allows me to drag the value, but blocks me from selecting a different value.

I've tried playing with the `OnMouse(Down|Move|Up)` events as below, but I'm missing something to get it working smoothly.  Especially as it seems the `OnMouseUp` event does not always fire when selecting an item from the list.

```
procedure TfrmMain.cboReasonsMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  fMouseDown := True;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.cboReasonsMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
begin
  if fMouseDown then
    if cboReasons.PressedPosition.X > 185 then begin
      cboReasons.DragMode := TDragMode.dmManual;
      cboReasons.Cursor := crDefault;
    end
    else begin
      cboReasons.DragMode := TDragMode.dmAutomatic;
      cboReasons.Cursor := crDrag;
    end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.cboReasonsMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  fMouseDown := False;
  cboReasons.DragMode := TDragMode.dmManual;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without dragmode dmautomatic. // Updated now with dragmode use

```
  uses FMX.Platform;

  procedure TForm1.ComboBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button:      TMouseButton;
    Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  //var
  //  ABitmap: TBitmap;
  //  DDService: IFMXDragDropService;
  //  D: TDragObject;
  begin
   {if (ssCtrl in Shift) then
begin
  ABitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    ABitmap := ComboBox1.MakeScreenshot;
    D.Source := Combobox1;
    if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService
      (IFMXDragDropService, IInterface(DDService)) then
      DDService.BeginDragDrop(Self, D, FMX.Graphics.TBitmap(ABitmap));
  finally
    ABitmap.Free;
  end;}
// without CTRL use, if mouse is not in the dropdown button
// 22-24 can be get from style ? Caution Don't take care of scale  
      if x>Combobox1.Width-24 then Combobox1.DragMode:=TDragMode.dmAutomatic;
end;
  
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Memo1DragDrop(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
const Point: TPointF);
  begin
    if TCombobox(Data.Source).ItemIndex > -1 then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(TCombobox(Data.Source).Selected.Text);
    // added
    TCombobox(Data.Source).DragMode:=TDragMode.dmManual; // reset to manuel 
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Memo1DragOver(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
const Point: TPointF; var Operation: TDragOperation);
  begin
    if (Data.Source <> Nil) 
       AND (Data.Source is TComboBox)       
     then
      Operation := TDragOperation.Move
    else
      Operation := TDragOperation.None;
   end;
```

Comment: This works a lot better, but one odd side effect is that when I select a new item, and then attempt to drag (without using the Ctrl key as I have not required that in the past and may be counter-intuitive for a non-technical user), at the completion of the drop, the Combobox list drops down.  I'm not seeing a method to close the list (the opposite of the DropDown method).

Comment: Just call the same `DropDown` method again to close an opened list. You can check the `DroppedDown` property to ensure that the list is opened.